# Umbraco 7 single page application routing

Tags: angularjs, url-rewriting, umbraco, umbraco7

I have a problem with my single page application made around Umbraco 7.
I would like to redirect all requests to AngularJS instead of Umbraco, for that I have added the following urlrewrite to UrlRewriting.config:

```
<add name="SPA"
     virtualUrl="^~/(?![0-9]+/)([^\?]*?)$"
     rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
     destinationUrl="~/"
     ignoreCase="true" />
```

But this redirects all responses to AngularJS, so now it not possible to open Umbraco at /umbraco. Does anyone know how to make a urlrewrite that redirects all responses to Angular except /umbraco?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the solution was easier than it looked. Think regular expressions always is like that.The regular expression says: "From the start of the string after the base Url (~) exclude umbraco and ucommerce and uCommerce, the rest goes to base url.

Here's my solution:

```
<add name="Eventcatering"
     virtualUrl="^~/(?!umbraco|ucommerce|uCommerce)(.*)"
     rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
     destinationUrl="~/"
     ignoreCase="true" />
```

I use the uCommerce package as well, which have some control API in /ucommerce, so these need to be excluded too.