# Umbraco - routes for Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, umbraco

In my Umbraco web application, I have two pages which are SPA angular applications. Let's call them /pageOne and /pageTwo.

When these pages are refreshed, I get a page not found error, due to Umbraco's routing.

Is it possible to re-write the routes so this does not occur?

I see from the below question

[Umbraco 7 single page application routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33688294/umbraco-7-single-page-application-routing)

this can be done, but in this example all of the URL redirects are given to Angular, whereas I only require two.

Would it be something along the lines of

```
<add name="SomeName"
     virtualUrl="^~/(? pages-which-are-not-angular-SPA-here )(.*)"
     rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
     destinationUrl="~/"
     ignoreCase="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want Umbraco to ignore two routes, you can add them to the umbracoReservedUrls property in the appSettings of the web.config file. The setting is a comma separated list of URLs that Umbraco should totally ignore. If you wanted to add more in future, you could group them all under a folder, e.g. /ang/pageOne and /ang/pageTwo and then add the /ang/ part to the umbracoReservedPaths setting, which is entire folders that Umbraco should ignore.